# Xcode ignore the -w compiler flag when treating all warnings as errors

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm compiling my project while treating all the warnings as error. Some of my files cannot be changed therefore i would like the complier to ignore the warnings in them. I used the -w compiler flag on those file, however when I compiling Xcode he ignores the -w and treats the warnings as errors. Is it possible to make him ignore those files? (Xcode ver 5.1.1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1150400/3800154
 Here you can disable the checkboxes for the various warnings you have active.